# fetch only content of email

Tags: python, imaplib

I'm attempting to return ONLY the message content of a message that I am fetching from an IMAP server.  I feel like I got this to work at one point without an issue, but I'm currently getting a bunch of garbage returned.  Here is the content I get back from the server currently (including a bunch of garbage that I don't want).

My code is something like the following:

```
server.select('INBOX')
status, ids = server.search(None, 'UnSeen')

latest_id = ids[0]
print 'latest id is', latest_id
status, msg_data = server.fetch(latest_id, '(RFC822)')
raw_data = msg_data[0][1]
print 'raw msg data: ', raw_data
```

My goal is to isolate the character string "Abc" out of this:

> raw msg data: Delivered-To:  Received: by 
>   with SMTP id k5csp25808iba;
>           Tue, 22 May 2012 16:52:37 -0700 (PDT) Return-Path: <3xSa8TyIUAIYBIBIEJFFGFA.BFBACICAAIB.dGgfq0IEl2373.5ysmo.qyyqvo.myw@grandcentral.bounces.google.com>
>   Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of
>   3xSa8TyIUAIYBIBIEJFFGFA.BFBACICAAIB.dGgfq0IEl2373.5ysmo.qyyqvo.myw@grandcentral.bounces.google.com
>   designates  as permitted sender) client-ip=10.52.24.68;
>   Authentication-Results: mr.google.com; spf=pass (google.com: domain of
>   3xSa8TyIUAIYBIBIEJFFGFA.BFBACICAAIB.dGgfq0IEl2373.5ysmo.qyyqvo.myw@grandcentral.bounces.google.com
>   designates  as permitted sender)
>   smtp.mail=3xSa8TyIUAIYBIBIEJFFGFA.BFBACICAAIB.dGgfq0IEl2373.5ysmo.qyyqvo.myw@grandcentral.bounces.google.com;
>   dkim=pass
>   header.i=3xSa8TyIUAIYBIBIEJFFGFA.BFBACICAAIB.dGgfq0IEl2373.5ysmo.qyyqvo.myw@grandcentral.bounces.google.com
>   Received: from mr.google.com ([10.52.24.68])
>           by  with SMTP id s4mr15641011vdf.3.1337730757212 (num_hops = 1);
>           Tue, 22 May 2012 16:52:37 -0700 (PDT) DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
>           d=google.com; s=20120113;
>           h=mime-version:references:message-id:date:subject:from:to
>            :content-type;
>           bh=KIYz0SegimNSAAbGsi5167k+DIHSSlVjHp4RK92QeKo=;
>           b=K2//5fPk82ocgnfM6iY4abv/RnxBzlbpnhSosuzkhf8cASjQmyLI0fshrY/xFWY1kh
>            dQHWDqnpdPW5JhF8kODPkX6nDUCTmA81954ROjmqorUHqoqrqNgcJg17M5PPhfMCduhm
>            HaavvpGomS8M29A2Yw81p6+BDSLHDOsVaqXKM1SuuBjslBYZZNEz3YNDsZWHWop64O6V
>            STWCiuXhdAwxqD3Ruuh1ZTbxrmHMimKZfGtF5wahvy8prRQibdBd21eW05fk7PHwalg9
>            vrsKpGD/xYzpGzEc7nUzIvirUlHFebN3r7JqO463ZKpWgKX/zEdG/uO2OFdxsYdqThow
>            EBDg== MIME-Version: 1.0 Received: by 10.52.24.68 with SMTP id s4mr10817316vdf.3.1337730757202; Tue, 22  May 2012 16:52:37 -0700
>   (PDT) References:
>   <+18184955650.77d431b4360d0f0785312b85196039cf7bf69257@txt.voice.google.com> Message-ID:
>   <+18184955650.d58cd371f90b1e89b989489c4752e917791953de@txt.voice.google.com> Date: Tue, 22 May 2012 23:52:37 +0000 Subject: SMS from 
>   From: ""
>   <.T6WVgq84bs@txt.voice.google.com> To:
>    Content-Type: text/plain;
>   charset=ISO-8859-1; format=flowed; delsp=yes
>
> Abc

Comment: Have you tried passing it to the classes in the stdlib that can parse it?

Comment: i tried list(), but i'm really not sure how to parse it with stdlib, honestly.  i'm sorry

Comment: i looked here: http://www.devshed.com/c/a/Python/Python-Email-Libraries-part-2-IMAP/3/ ... it doesn't help much because there is no reference to try to get the msg content.  i try BODY[TEXT] to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find a reference for the strings passed to server.fetch() (as mentioned above) [here](http://www.devshed.com/c/a/Python/Python-Email-Libraries-part-2-IMAP/3/).
This answered my question, since I can isolate the string I want via the following:

```
status, msg_data = server.fetch(some_id, '(UID BODY[TEXT])')
```

Answer (score 0):

[`email.parser.Parser().parse()`](http://docs.python.org/library/email.parser.html#email.parser.Parser.parse), [`email.parser.Parser().parsestr()`](http://docs.python.org/library/email.parser.html#email.parser.Parser.parsestr)

Comment: sorry, i don't think i need to get this complicated.  i would rather do something like server.fetch(latest_id, '(BODY[HEADER])'), but i don't know what to use to get just the msg content